# can I pass default argument to parameter of user-defined class type?

Tags: c++, arguments, default

I'm getting the error "default argument not at end of parameter list" in the following line.

```
Date(int m = 1, int d = 2, int y = 1900, Time); // default constructor
```

Time is a user-defined class. Is it possible to provide Time with default argument? If yes, how? If no, how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either move `Time` to the beginning, or give it a default argument based off whatever constructors it has.

```
Date(Time, int m = 1, int d = 2, int y = 1900);
//or
Date(int m = 1, int d = 2, int y = 1900, Time = Time(/*ctor args can go here*/));
```

Alternatively if `Time` has a converting constructor, you could supply a value of that type as the default argument.

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks :)